# numpy.corrcoef to evaluate the best x or feature column related to y label output

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to use `np.corrcoef`  to evaluate the best feature x in comparison with the label y. But I think there must be a better way to do this.
The corr array will look like --> `[0.73117578 0.40620284 0.82562664]` and then I select index 2 which is my best feature.

```py
data_x = np.array([[0.885, 0.330, 9.100],[0.725, 0.390, 10.900],[0.560, 0.500, 9.400],[0.735, 0.570, 9.800],[0.610, 0.630, 8.400],[0.260, 0.630, 11.800],[0.500, 0.680, 10.500],[0.320, 0.780, 10.000]])
data_y = np.array([4.000, 5.000, 6.000, 5.000, 3.000, 8.000, 7.000, 6.000])

corr = []
for i in range(0, len(data_y)):
    featureX = data_x[:, i].reshape(-1)
    matrix = np.corrcoef(featureX, data_y)
    corr.append(matrix[1, 0])

corr = np.array(corr)
corr = np.absolute(corr)
splitXi = np.argmax(corr)
splitXi = int(splitXi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data_x` has columns as features, and rows as observations. So, you can use `np.transpose` or `rowvar=False` as an argument to `np.corrcoef`.

```py
data_x = np.array([[0.885, 0.330, 9.100],[0.725, 0.390, 10.900],[0.560, 0.500, 9.400],[0.735, 0.570, 9.800],[0.610, 0.630, 8.400],[0.260, 0.630, 11.800],[0.500, 0.680, 10.500],[0.320, 0.780, 10.000]])
data_y = np.array([4.000, 5.000, 6.000, 5.000, 3.000, 8.000, 7.000, 6.000])

corr = np.abs(np.corrcoef(data_x, data_y, rowvar=False)[-1, :-1])
corr
>>> array([0.73117578, 0.40620284, 0.82562664])

splitXi = int(np.argmax(corr))
splitXi
>>> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're looking for *feature importance* and rather than correlation (correct me if I'm wrong).

One way to find out feature importance would be to use a [RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html):

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor 

data_x = np.array([[0.885, 0.330, 9.100],[0.725, 0.390, 10.900],[0.560, 0.500, 9.400],[0.735, 0.570, 9.800],[0.610, 0.630, 8.400],[0.260, 0.630, 11.800],[0.500, 0.680, 10.500],[0.320, 0.780, 10.000]])
data_y = np.array([4.000, 5.000, 6.000, 5.000, 3.000, 8.000, 7.000, 6.000])

rfr = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=1000, random_state=2452354).fit(data_x, data_y)
print(rfr.feature_importances_) # [0.48855445 0.12778678 0.38365877]
```

Answer (score 0):

feature 1 is negative and strongly correlated (-.73)
feature 2 is positive and weakly correlated (.40)
feature 3 is positive and strong correlated (.82%)

corrcoef examines variance from the slope of a line.  The less variance in distance from the slope of a line the higher the correlation or line fit to the data feature.

```
data_x = np.array([
[0.885, 0.330, 9.100],
[0.725, 0.390, 10.900],
[0.560, 0.500, 9.400],
[0.735, 0.570, 9.800],
[0.610, 0.630, 8.400],
[0.260, 0.630, 11.800],
[0.500, 0.680, 10.500],
[0.320, 0.780, 10.000]])
data_y = np.array([4.000, 5.000, 6.000, 5.000, 3.000, 8.000, 7.000, 6.000])

data=np.concatenate((data_x,data_y[:,None]),axis=1)

#print(data[:,0:3])
#print(data[:,3])
#correlation = np.corrcoef(data[:,0], data[:,3],rowvar=False)[0,1]
#correlation = np.corrcoef(data[:,1], data[:,3],rowvar=False)[0,1]
#correlation = np.corrcoef(data[:,2], data[:,3],rowvar=False)[0,1]
correlation = np.corrcoef(data[:,0:3], data[:,3],rowvar=False)[0,1]

print(correlation)

def combine_data(data_x, data_y):
    data_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(data_x)):
        data_dict[i] = [data_x[i], data_y[i]]
    return data_dict

def sort_data(data_dict):
    sorted_data = sorted(data_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
    return sorted_data

data_dict = combine_data(data_x, data_y)
sorted_data = sort_data(data_dict)

for i in range(len(sorted_data)):
    plt.scatter(sorted_data[i][1][0][0], sorted_data[i][1][0][1], c='b')
plt.show()
for i in range(len(sorted_data)):        
    plt.scatter(sorted_data[i][1][0][1], sorted_data[i][1][0][1], c='r')
plt.show()
for i in range(len(sorted_data)):        
    plt.scatter(sorted_data[i][1][0][2], sorted_data[i][1][0][1], c='g')
plt.show()
```

if your looking for feature importance

```
 from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

 forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=250, random_state=0)
 forest.fit(data_x, data_y)
 importances = forest.feature_importances_
 std = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in 
 forest.estimators_],axis=0)
 indices = np.argsort(importances)[::-1]

 print("Feature ranking:")
 for f in range(data_x.shape[1]):
     print("%d. feature %d (%f)" % (f + 1, indices[f], 
     importances[indices[f]]))
```

output

```
 features 0 is highest ranking

 Feature ranking:
 1. feature 0 (0.339678)
 2. feature 2 (0.334904)
 3. feature 1 (0.325418)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

In this situation, you may implement the correlation yourself, to be good at both speed and memory footprint:

```py
def corrwith(X, y, rowvar=True):
    X = np.asarray(X)
    if not rowvar:
        X = X.T
    y = np.asarray(y)
    a = np.mean(X * y, axis=1) - np.mean(X, axis=1) * np.mean(y)
    b1 = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(X), axis=1) - np.square(np.mean(X, axis=1)))
    b2 = np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(y)) - np.square(np.mean(y)))
    return a / (b1 * b2)
```

Example:

```py
corr = corrwith(data_x, data_y, rowvar=False)
```

Tested against `pandas.corrwith` ("pandas method" below)

---

Original answer:

## Clarification of the accepted answer

First I want to explain why [armamut's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66183770/7881370) works.
`np.corrcoef(data_x, data_y, rowvar=False)` is equivalent to `np.corrcoef(np.concatenate([data_x, data_y[:, np.newaxis]], axis=1), rowvar=False)`, of which the return value at index `(i, j)` corresponds to the correlation coefficient between column i and column j of `data_x`. Thus the slice `[-1, :-1]` means to find the correlations between the last column, which is `data_y`, and all but the last column, which are columns of `data_x`.

## Alternative approach

Apparently there are two methods to find the correlations: one using `numpy.corrcoef`, and the other using `pandas.DataFrame.corrwith`, i.e.:

```py
corr = np.corrcoef(data_x, data_y, rowvar=False)[-1, :-1]
```

and

```py
import pandas as pd
corr = pd.DataFrame(data_x).corrwith(pd.Series(data_y)).to_numpy()
```

## Profiling

Profiling using Python `timeit` module tells which method is best.
The profiling code is:

```py
from timeit import timeit
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

setup = '''\
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
X = np.random.randn(100, {})
y = np.random.randn(100)
'''


def test_match():
    X = np.random.randn(100, 10)
    y = np.random.randn(100)
    c1 = np.corrcoef(X, y, rowvar=False)[-1, :-1]
    c2 = pd.DataFrame(X).corrwith(pd.Series(y)).to_numpy()
    assert c1.shape == c2.shape
    assert np.allclose(c1, c2)


def time_np(n_var):
    k = max(1, 20000 // n_var)
    return timeit(
        '_ = np.corrcoef(X, y, rowvar=False)[-1, :-1]',
        setup.format(n_var),
        number=k) / k


def time_pd(n_var):
    k = max(1, 20000 // n_var)
    return timeit(
        '_ = pd.DataFrame(X).corrwith(pd.Series(y)).to_numpy()',
        setup.format(n_var),
        number=k) / k


def main():
    n_vars = np.array([1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 20000])
    np_times = np.array([time_np(n) for n in tqdm(n_vars, desc='np')])
    pd_times = np.array([time_pd(n) for n in tqdm(n_vars, desc='pd')])
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(n_vars, np.log10(np_times), '^-', label='numpy method')
    ax.plot(n_vars, np.log10(pd_times), 's-', label='pandas method')
    ax.set_xlabel('# of variables')
    ax.set_ylabel('log10 of seconds consumed')
    ax.legend()
    ax.grid()
    fig.savefig(Path.home() / 'Downloads' / 'prof.jpg')
    plt.close(fig)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The plot of the profiling result is:

[image: time consumption of the numpy and pandas methods]

According to the result, when the features aren't that many, using numpy is much better than using pandas.
However, as the number of features increases, the difference in performance gradually decreases.
At some point using pandas will be faster than using numpy.

Another critical issue with numpy is that the memory consumption is $O(n^2)$ where $n$ is the number of features.
This means that, at least on my computer, the correlation matrix of 50000 features won't fit into memory, and so the numpy method will definitely fail.

## Conclusion

If there aren't so many features, stick to the numpy method.
Otherwise, considering first converting the arrays to pandas DataFrame and Series, using `corrwith`, and finally converting back to numpy arrays.

Comment: Kevin, I copied your corrwith function and pasted the OP's data_x and data_y to test and it came back with ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,3) (8,).  Do you have any idea why?  In my case, I prefer to not use Dataframe.corrwith.

Comment: Never mind, I set rowvar=False and it came out fine